# Dealing with very large existing database in android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have very large MS database about 400 MB, what is the best way to use it without make it online, I did that in symbian with j2me and it just take 70 MB in jar file by converting it to a text file.

Comment: Did you tried to you use SQLite DB in Android? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db